# AngularJS post Data to nodeJs/Sequelize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am creating an e-commerce web site with Nodejs/Sequelize and AngularJs.

I am actually got this starter [AngularJS starter](https://github.com/popularowl/angular-starter).

In my project I got 2 folders :

- Client (which contains AngularJS starter folders)

[image: Client folder]

- Server (which contains my server.js

[image: Server folder]

I would like to register a user, I got my "registeredView.html" with a form :

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
            <input type="text" name=firstname ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="firstname" required=" ">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" placeholder="lastname" required=" ">
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email Address" required=" ">
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" required=" ">
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" ng-model="user.confirm_password" placeholder="Password Confirmation" required=" ">
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
```

For now, I could get those datas in my "RegisteredController" thanks to the $scope.user but I don't know how to send those data to my server.

I am using express module so I tried with $http.post like this :

```
    .controller('RegisteredController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $http.post('/registered', $scope.user)
        then(function (response) {
            console.log("posted")
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.error(response)
        })
    }
}]);
```

And on my "server.js" I tried to get this post like this :

```
app.get('/registered', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body)
res.end();
```

});

But it dont works..

What I wrong ? Some Advice ? 
I need your helps guys please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments there are 3 immediately apparent issues:

- Your server is expecting a `get`, not a `post`, change `app.get('/registered'...)` to `app.post('/registered'...)`.
- You're missing a dot here: `$http.post('/registered', $scope.user)then(function (response) {`, between the closing `)` and `then`.
- You need to mark your `$http` to be injected, as with `$scope` - change `['$scope', function ($scope, $http)` to `['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http)`.

To be able to do something with your posted data you should check out [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). After requiring it you can do the following - `app.use(bodyParser.json())`. Then you should have access to `req.body` which should contain your user parsed as a javascript object.

Comment: Yep, I just noticed it and tried to change to app.post but it is still not work

Comment: You're missing a dot here: `$http.post('/registered', $scope.user)then(function (response) {`, between the closing `)` and `then`. If that doesn't help you're going to have to give us a more specific idea of what doesn't work, is there an error?

Comment: And even if I got datas in the app.post request.body, how can I manage to process datas ?

Comment: @UncleDava Oops ill fix that

Comment: @UncleDava I fixed it and got TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Comment: You need to mark your `$http` to be injected, as with `$scope` - change `['$scope', function ($scope, $http)` to `['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http)`

Comment: Yep it works, thanks @UncleDave. how can I manage to process datas now please?

Comment: You should check out [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). After requiring it you can do the following - `app.use(bodyParser.json())`. Then you should have access to `req.body` which should contain your user parsed as a javascript object.